# How to pass data of the second table view cell when i click the first table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making an app in which I have to pass the data of the table view cell the user clicks and also the data of the second table view cell.

I am able to pass the data of the current table view cell by using:

```
let Level2 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReportVC") as? ReportVC {
                        Level2.passedRes = item.patient
                        Level2.passedRoom = item.room
                        Level2.passResImg = item.resImage
                        Level2.selectedBeacon = beac
                        self.show(Level2, sender: nil)
```

Also if no table view cell exists after that, I just want to pass no more table view cell's exist.

[image]

Comment: Basically pass data always from the **model** (the data source) rather than from the **view** (the cell).

Comment: I am new, can you link me to something, that would help me out more. So using one of the predefined tableview's datasource functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing You can do there is in

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

you choose the images or text or data that You want to pass to second VC (if you want to choose two indexPaths just add +1 on the second one(indexPath + 1)) and store it on UserDefaults. And then in 2nd VC You can retrieve it from UserDefaults. 
I hope this answer helped You!

Answer (score 0):

To get items from your datasource you could use `dataSource[indexPath.row]`, indexPath you could get from the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. To get next item you need to check if it is not last (indexPath.row < dataSource.count - 1), if not just increment current indexPath.